# Iterating over a dictionary example: Gradebook statistics

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out why my for loop is iterating over the first item in my dictionary instead of through the first index of each list in the dictionary:

Write a program that uses the keys(), values(), and/or items() dict methods to find statistics about the student_grades dictionary. Find the following:

Print the name and grade percentage of the student with the highest total of points.
Find the average score of each assignment.
Find and apply a curve to each student's total score, such that the best student has 100% of the total points.

Here's my code:

```
student_grades = {
    'Tricia': [99, 92, 95, 89, 99],
    'Andrew': [56, 79, 90, 22, 50],
    'Nisreen': [88, 62, 68, 75, 78],
    'Alan': [95, 88, 92, 85, 85],
    'Chang': [76, 88, 85, 82, 90]    
}

highest = 0
score = 0
for student, grades in student_grades.items():    
    percent = sum(grades)/len(grades)    
    if percent >= highest:
        highest = percent
        print('Student with Highest total points:')
        print(student, ':', highest)
        print()
        print('Average for each assignment:')
        i = 0
        for i in range(len(grades)):
            score += grades[i] #FIX ME
            print('Assignment', i+1, ':', score / len(grades))        
        print()
        print('Curve:')
    curve = percent / highest 
    print(student, ':', round((curve * 100), 1))
```

Output is:

Student with Highest total points:
Tricia : 94.8

Average for each assignment:
Assignment 1 : 19.8
Assignment 2 : 38.2
Assignment 3 : 57.2
Assignment 4 : 75.0
Assignment 5 : 94.8

Curve:
Tricia : 100.0
Andrew : 62.7
Nisreen : 78.3
Alan : 93.9
Chang : 88.8

Assignment Average should be:
Assignment 1 : 82.8
Assignment 2 : 81.8
Assignment 3 : 86
Assignment 4 : 70.6
Assignment 5 : 80.4

Comment: You'll need to make two passes through the data.  First pass to get the highest score and the second pass to print the results.

Answer (score 0):

By creating a `dict` of assignment grades you can track averages easily.  Also, you need to use one sweep of `student_grades` to determine `highest`.  Here's a couple of ideas which I hope might help;

```
from collections import defaultdict
from collections import namedtuple
from numpy import average

student_grades = {
    'Tricia': [99, 92, 95, 89, 99],
    'Andrew': [56, 79, 90, 22, 50],
    'Nisreen': [88, 62, 68, 75, 78],
    'Alan': [95, 88, 92, 85, 85],
    'Chang': [76, 88, 85, 82, 90],    
}

Grade = namedtuple('Grade', ['grade', 'name'])
highest_so_far = Grade(grade=-1, name=None)
assignment_grades = defaultdict(list)

for student, grades in student_grades.items():
    # get average grade
    percent = average(grades)

    # "transpose" the student_grades dict to an assignment_grades dict
    for i, grade in enumerate(grades, start=1):
        assignment_grades[i].append(grade)

    # track the highest average grade so far
    if percent >= highest_so_far.grade:
        highest_so_far = Grade(grade=percent, name=student)

# show the student with the highest average  
print('Student with Highest average points:')
print(highest_so_far.name, ':', highest_so_far.grade)

# print average grades by assignment 
print('\nAverage for each assignment:')
for assignment, grades in assignment_grades.items():
    print(f'Assignment {assignment}: {average(grades)} ')

# determine the max grade for each assignment
high_grades = [max(grades) for grades in assignment_grades.values()]

# print each student's grade as a % of the high grade for each assignment
print('\nCurve:')
for student, grades in student_grades.items():
    print(f'{student:<8}: ' + ' '.join((f'{100*grade/high:>6.1f}' 
            for grade, high in zip(grades, high_grades))))

# Output
# Student with Highest average points:
# Tricia : 94.8
# 
# Average for each assignment:
# Assignment 1: 82.8
# Assignment 2: 81.8
# Assignment 3: 86.0
# Assignment 4: 70.6
# Assignment 5: 80.4
#
# Curve:
# Tricia  :  100.0  100.0  100.0  100.0  100.0
# Andrew  :   56.6   85.9   94.7   24.7   50.5
# Nisreen :   88.9   67.4   71.6   84.3   78.8
# Alan    :   96.0   95.7   96.8   95.5   85.9
# Chang   :   76.8   95.7   89.5   92.1   90.9
```